# How to display row values as column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in below format:

```
Table_1 (Tax Types)

TaxTypeID   Code       Description  LocationID
 1          TaxA         DescA         1
 2          TaxB         DescB         1
 3          TaxC         DescB         1

Table_2 (Tax Plans)

PlanID    Name   Description   LocationID
 1        Plan1     Plan1          1

Table_3 (Cross Reference)

TaxTypeID   PlanID    TaxPercentage 
   1           1          5.00 
   2           1          7.00
```

So I need to write a query which outputs below result when Plan_Id is passed and also by matching Table 1 and 2 LocationID:

```
PlanID  Name    TaxA   TaxB   TaxC
   1    Plan1   5.00   7.00   0.00
```

If table_3 does not have cross reference between table_1 and table_2 percentage should be displayed as 0.00. Mainly I need to display rows in Table_1(tax types) as column names in my output and this should be dynamic, based on rows in Table_1(tax types). So, if a new tax type row "TaxD" is added, out should have a new column TaxD with 0.00 as percentage.

I know by using Pivot in SQL,we can get row values as column names and I tried below query

```
select *
from
(
select TaxTypeId,Code from Table_1  ) as p
pivot 
(
max(Code)
for Code in ( [TaxA],[TaxB],[TaxC]) 
)as pvt
```

But it is not close to what I need.

Comment: You're missing some joins to Table2 and Table3

Comment: In my query I have hard coded column names in pivot part, but in reality new rows will be added by users so I'm not sure how to automatically set "for code in (rows collection)" in my query before adding joins.

Comment: Regardless, you're still missing some joins...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `max(TaxPercentage)` instead of `max(code)` in pivot

```
select * from
(
SELECT c.planid,c.NAME,taxpercentage,a.Code 
FROM   table_1 a 
       JOIN table_3 b 
         ON a.taxtypeid = b.taxtypeid 
       JOIN table_2 c 
         ON c.planid = b.planid 
) as p
pivot 
(
max(TaxPercentage)
for Code in ( [TaxA],[TaxB],[TaxC]) 
)as pvt
```

If the values in code is not fixed then you need to use dynamic pivot

```
declare @sql varchar(8000),@col_list varchar(8000),@pivot_list varchar(8000)

set @col_list =stuff((select distinct  ',Coalesce('+ quotename(Code) + ',0) as '+ quotename(Code) from Table_1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')

set @pivot_list =stuff((select distinct  ','+quotename(Code) from Table_1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')

set @sql  = 'select * from
(
SELECT c.planid,c.NAME,taxpercentage,a.Code 
FROM   table_1 a 
       JOIN table_3 b 
         ON a.taxtypeid = b.taxtypeid 
       JOIN table_2 c 
         ON c.planid = b.planid 
) as p
pivot 
(
max(TaxPercentage)
for Code in ( '+@pivot_list+') 
)as pvt'
--print @sql
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Your query worked, thanks. Quick question, in inner query I'm checking if taxpercentage value is null and setting it to 0, but still output returns null if cross reference does not exits in Table_3. I cannot check this in outer query since column names are dynamic. Is there any option to return taxpercentage as 0 if it is null?

Comment: @user2502961 - Updated..check now